# Nodejs Redis and Waterfall not passing value to next function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, waterfall

I've been trying to follow the async waterfall example shown as below;

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Here is my version of the code;

```
var successfulRecords = 0 //successfulRecords holds the number of successfully processed rows

       //Delete existing records for prepaid model before adding new records 
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                redis.del("prepaid",function(err,data){
                    if (err){
                        logger.debug(err);
                    }

                    SCORES_CACHE = new Map(
                        rows.map(function(row){
                            redis.zadd("prepaid",row[1],row[0],function(err,response){

                                if (err){
                                    logger.debug(err);
                                }

                                if (response==1){
                                    successfulRecords=successfulRecords+1;
                                    console.log(successfulRecords);
                                }
                            })
                        })
                        )

                })
                callback(null,successfulRecords);
            },

            function(arg1,callback){
                console.log('hello, waiting for arg1: ',arg1);
            }
            ], function(err,result){

            });
```

Code supposed to work like this

1. Insert record into redis DB
2. If successful, update the successful record counter
3. Pass the final count of the successfulRecord variable to the next function

However, i keep getting this result instead;

```
hello, waiting for arg1:  0
```

How can i fix this? Been working on this for hours. Did I not place the callback correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This `callback(null,successfulRecords);` is called before the `redis.del` is complete. Move it one line up.

```
function(callback){
    redis.del("prepaid",function(err,data){
        if (err){
            logger.debug(err);
        }

        SCORES_CACHE = new Map(
            rows.map(function(row){
                redis.zadd("prepaid",row[1],row[0],function(err,response){

                    if (err){
                        logger.debug(err);
                    }

                    if (response==1){
                        successfulRecords=successfulRecords+1;
                        console.log(successfulRecords);
                    }
                })
            })
        )
        callback(null,successfulRecords); //One line up
    })

}
```